# XPath: nodes defined in different ways

Tags: java, xpath, xstream

I have an XML document that is generated by persisting an object tree into an XML. In this tree nodes (objects) of a certain type can occur in different manners:

1. They are referenced from an other object, in XML terms this means they are a child of a node that represents an object. The first time this happens the node has an `id` attribute and is serialized in situ through child nodes:

```
<productionLocation class="ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City" id="935">
    <wares id="936">
        <entry>
        <ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.product.EWare ware="BEER"/>
        <ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.product.AmountablePrice id="937">
            <amount class="javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty" id="938">127</amount>
            <sum class="javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty" id="939">2760.0</sum>
        </ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.product.AmountablePrice>
        </entry>
    </wares>
    <name>London</name>
    ...
</productionLocation>
```

2. If the same object is referenced by another node, instead of an `id` attribute there is a `reference` attribute and there are no child nodes representing the object:

```
<birthPlace class="ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City" reference="935"/>
```

3. Similar to the first case the node may be referenced from a collection type object (map, list, ...), in which case there will not be a `class` attribute but that value will be the node name. There will either be an `id` or a `reference` attribute:

```
<productionAndConsumption id="240">
    <entry>
    <ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City id="241">
        <wares id="242">
            <entry>
                <ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.product.EWare ware="BEER"/>
                <ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.product.AmountablePrice id="243">
                <amount class="javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty" id="244">43</amount>
                <sum class="javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty" id="245">0.0</sum>
                </ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.product.AmountablePrice>
            </entry>
        </wares>
        <name>London</name>
        ...
    </ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City>
    </entry>
</productionAndConsumption>
```

What I am trying to achieve is getting a node list that represents all nodes defining objects of type `ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City`.

What I have got so far is a XPath expression for the first two cases:
`//*[@class='ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City' and @id]`

What I struggle with is comming up with the second part that selects all nodes `ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City` that have an `id` attribute and combining it with the above.

**Clarification:**

Given a `className` I need to find all nodes that have a class attribute of said `className` and an `id` attribute or all nodes `className` with an `id` attribute.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the xpath expression in the question only selects the first case (the `<productionLocation>` element). Are you looking for one expression that will select all three elements (this one plus `<birthPlace>` and `<productionAndConsumption>`)?

Comment: @JackFleeting Updated the question a bit. I need an expression for cases 1 and 3. Be aware that the third case can also have a variant where there is a `reference` attribute instead of an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath expression is composed by two separate expression that combined with an `OR`.

The first part is from the question itself and matches the case 1) and excludes cases 2):

```
//*[@class='ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City' and @id]
```

The second part selects and node with `ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City` that has an id attribute:

```
//ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City[@id]
```

Combining both together:

```
//*[@class='ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City' and @id] 
| //ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.city.impl.City[@id]
```